# Bluetooth worked once with MT7630E on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, 17.10, mediatek

I'm using Ubuntu without trying to make the Bluetooth work (because I don't really need it) for more than a year, and I'm aware it doesn't work because my wireless adapter isn't originally compatible with Linux. So on every kernel upgrade I reinstall the MT7630E driver which comes from [this git](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E) in order to use the Wi-Fi, but I stopped worrying about making the Bluetooth work as well...

Until on a reboot the Bluetooth started to work (I found out because I had a the tray icon which is usually not there), and I thought that was a good thing up to when I plugged of the Ethernet cable and noticed the Wi-Fi didn't work (i.e. no option to turn it on, like when I have to reinstall the driver). So I just rebooted, because I have more use of Wi-Fi than Bluetooth, and all was back as usual (Wi-Fi, no Bluetooth).

As I said I don't really mind that the Bluetooth works or not (better if it does though), **but *why* would it work *once* and not the rest of the time ?**

---

The only "special" actions prior to this event, that I can think of, are :

1. I installed `grub-customizer` (which I no longer had since a fresh install a month ago) ;
2. I *rebooted* under Windows 10, which I don't use often (so this is why I hadn't installed `grub-customizer` yet) ;
3. Did what I had to do on Windows (maybe some upgrades as well)
4. I *rebooted* back to Ubuntu (I always reboot and don't shut down to ensure there is not hardware conflict - due to hibernation or I don't know what - when I switch between OSs).

And then was the Bluetooth working.

Comment: I don't see how it is a duplicate of this thread, I mentioned that I installed the driver for MT7630E, _and the installation works_ because the Wi-Fi works. This other post does not provide any answers concerning Bluetooth-specific issues